# AWS Serverless IdentityPoolRoleAttachment

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

So, I'm creating a role for my Cognito users to be able to call API Gateway:

```
    IdentityAuthenticatedRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Federated: "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
              Action:
                - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
              Condition:
                StringEquals: 
                  "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud":
                    - Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
                ForAnyValue:StringLike:
                  "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": authenticated
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: CognitoGatewayExecute
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - "execute-api:Invoke"
                  Resource: "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
        MaxSessionDuration: 3600
```

Then I'm attaching the role to my IdentityPoolRoleAttachment:

```
CognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment:
  DependsOn: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
  Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolId:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
          - ''
    Roles:
      authenticated:
        Fn:GetAtt
          - IdentityAuthenticatedRole
          - Arn
```

According to the docs it should work, but it of course does not:

```
CognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment - Access to Role 'Fn:GetAtt - IdentityAuthenticatedRole - Arn' is forbidden.
```

Can someone please shed some light on this?

P.S. As I've already pasted this snippet, there is one more thing: I'm using Fn::Join, because otherwise I'm greeted with "Is not of type String" error, is there a better way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Syntax Error**

Your `Fn::GetAtt` syntax is just a little off.  You need two colons between `Fn` and `GetAtt`, and then you need a colon at the end of that line.  Like this:

```
      authenticated:
        Fn::GetAtt:
```

This will fix the strange error message that contains `Fn:GetAtt`... where a real role name should be.

**Fn::Join**

You can get rid of the `Fn::Join` call by just using `Ref` like so:

```
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolId: 
      Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
```

**DependsOn**

The `DependsOn` line is fine, but not needed.  CloudFormation is smart enough to figure out this dependency for you.

**YAML note**

Finally, while this boils down to a readability preference, I usually put short lists (like the ones you pass to `Fn::GetAtt`) in square brackets.  So you can replace this:

```
  authenticated:
    Fn::GetAtt:
      - IdentityAuthenticatedRole
      - Arn
```

with this:

```
      authenticated:
        Fn::GetAtt: [IdentityAuthenticatedRole, Arn]
```

**Rewritten**

The result is shorter, and arguably easier to read. Combining these suggestions results in this role attachment resource:

```
CognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolId: 
      Ref: CognitoIdentityPoolStandardUserIdentityPool
    Roles:
      authenticated:
        Fn::GetAtt: [IdentityAuthenticatedRole, Arn]
```

Tested using *Serverless* 1.27.2

Comment: Thanks, fixed all of my issues. :)